# Generating ggplot2 plots from c++

Tags: c++, c, r

I'm developing an application in c++ that requires drawing lots of plots. In this respect, taking into account that I have a modest experience with R and ggplot2, I am currently generating scripts in R and executing them from c++ via Rscript y system(). However, I wonder if there is any library or interface that allows generating plots in ggplot2 from c or c++ that will further facilitate the process.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One trick that you can use is to embed python into your application, how to do this is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/embedding.html), and then use a python ggplot library such as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ggplot - this will remove the requirement to have R & ggplot2 installed on the target system.

This usage is covered by the python licence, PSF Licence, and under the ggplot BSD licence.

The good news is that this is a cross platform solution and both are gratis.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Qt, I would recommend QCustomPlot(http://qcustomplot.com/) - a very nice library written in c++. It has very good documentation, has forum where you can answer questions if you have some problems.